# URL Protocol Handler - "this link needs to be opened with an application"

Tags: iis, registry, protocols

I've created a custom protocol handler for URLs to launch an application from within a browser, this all works as desired.

The problem I do have is that on the first launch at the moment the user is required presented with a dialog that states:

```
"this link needs to be opened with an application"
```

Is there any way of stopping this by telling the OS that the protocol is already trusted and it should carry on with launching the application?

As I understand it at the moment this is a browser specific scenario so I'd have to complete this step for each browser installed where as I'd like to be able to tell the whole system that the protocol and associated application are trusted.

At the moment the protocol handler is simple .exe that I manually copied into Program Files not sure if this makes a difference to the level of trust or not in this scenario.

Comment: have you found any solution ???